# What are the shorthand operators for TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, operators

I've been using TensorFlow for very little but it seems promising. I'm doing the Coursera second course from DeepLearning.ai (Improving Deep Neural Networks: Hyperparameter tuning, Regularization and Optimization).

I noticed that there is an equivalent(ish) to simple operations like:

- tf.matmul(a,b) ≈ a @ b
- tf.add(a,b) ≈ a + b

I prefer shorthand operations because they might make code easier to read. So...

**What are all the shorthand operators?**

**Is there some place where I can find all the possible operations?**

Also, I would appreciate to hear some feedback on whether it is a good practice or not to use these shorthand operators...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific of tensorflow but a functionality of the python language. By defining some special member functions, you enable the use of those "shortcuts" -- for example if you implement the `__add__` member function then you use `+` to call this function.

You can find more about those [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) regarding "numeric" operators, and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) regarding "container" operators (such as `[]`). There are some more on the same page.

The fact that this is a python functionality, means that they may depend on the version of python you are using. I am thinking more particularly to `@` which came in python 3.5 and therefore cannot be used in python 2.7 AFAIK.

Those shortcuts make the code easier to read and I have not seen any induced penalty so far, so you can use at will.

Comment: I just found out about a nifty advantage from using the full function statements in TensorFlow (i.e. tf.matmul(a,b) vs a@b) and it is that you can name operations (apparently you can name everything in TF). Well, what does it mean? you ask... It means that when using a tool such as [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) you can easily find out what that operation was by its name. Probably not all operations should be named but you ca do so and make it easier to debug a graph.

Comment: @loco.loop True -- although I personally find scopes to be my main tool for organizing a graph. I name scopes and variables, very rarely operations. But that is a personal standpoint of course.